# MongoDB Equivalent to SQL query with Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to know how to use `where` in MongoDB queries using Java Driver.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 WHERE COLOUM3 = 'KeyWord';
```

I have a key Name and its value, and i want to find some other key/value. I think i can use `$where` for that. But, i dont know its syntax in java.

How shall i use `where` in my mongo queries?

Any suggestions would be appreciative!!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't generally need to use $where ...

You should be using the "document-style query" **find()**

Basically **find()** is MongoDB's version of where ...

If you have a collection called **mycollection** and a attribute called **attribute1** (this is exactly like your **COLUMN1**)

So to get results like this SQL query ...

```
SELECT * WHERE COLOUM3 = 'KeyWord';
```

Via the MongoDB shell, you'd use **find()** like so ...

```
> db.mycollection.find({attribute1:"KeyWord"})
```

You really shouldn't need to use $where for most any normal mongodb query.

Lots more help here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying

Answer (score 1):

There is a site called [www.querymongo.com](http://www.querymongo.com) that translates SQL syntax into MongoDB syntax.  It's really useful for cases like this.

In the case of the example above:

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM collection WHERE COLOUM3 = 'KeyWord';
```

Becomes this in MongoDB:

```
db.collection.find({
    "COLOUM3": "KeyWord"
});
```

Comment: This appears to be undisclosed self-promotion. Please be aware that this is against the rules on Stack Overflow and will quickly get you marked as a spammer if continued.